# Java how to use Timer for a minigame

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to make a "fastwriting" minigame... The user has to write the word in 5 seconds, but I can't fint a way to make the timer restart every time the user writes the word... The game stops after 5 seconds even if the user writes the word.
If user writes correctly the random word, the program sends a new message with a new random word... If the word is not correct, the program stops.

```
    public boolean playable = true;

@Override
public void onGuildMessageReceived(@Nonnull GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {

    if (!event.getMessage().getAuthor().isBot()) {

        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {

            if (playable) {

                word = findWord(); //Random Word

                EmbedBuilder fast = new EmbedBuilder();
                fast.setTitle("Write as Fast as you can!");
                fast.setDescription("The word is: ");

                MessageEmbed embed = fast.build();

                event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed).queue(message -> {

                    fast.setTitle("Write as Fast as you can!");
                    fast.setDescription("The word is: **" + word + "**");

                    message.editMessage(fast.build()).queueAfter(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                });

                Timer timer = new Timer();


                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override

                        public void run() {

                            playable = false;
                            System.out.println("STOP");

                        }
                    }, 5 * 1000);



                score++;

            }

        } else if (!event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(word) && !event.getMessage().getAuthor().isBot()){

            playable = false;
            EmbedBuilder loose = new EmbedBuilder();
            loose.setTitle("Wrong word, STOP");
            loose.setDescription("Score: " + punteggio);

            event.getChannel().sendMessage(loose.build()).queue();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many threads does the `game` use? Can the operation be blocking for the totality of the 5 seconds? Are you restricted to using a TimerTask object? Can you please provide more code for context.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would use a Swing timer.  You can either implement the `ActionListener` interface or use a `lambda` as I did below.

```
    volatile boolean playable;
    volatile boolean reset = false;
    Timer timer = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SuperTest().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        timer = new Timer(5000, (ae)-> {
           if (!reset) { 
               System.out.println("STOP");
               playable = false;
               timer.stop();
           } else {
               timer.start();
               reset = false;
           }
        });
        timer.start();

        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(;;) {
            String s = input.nextLine(); 
            reset = true;
        }   
    }
```

When the user types in a word in the allotted time, the reset is set to true. This should keep working until the user misses the timeout.

Note: local variables must be effectively final so `playable` must be an instance field if you want to change it when the time goes off.